# Downloading multiple files using PHP ZipArchive

Tags: php, php-ziparchive

I am trying to randomly download some files.

I apologize because I posted it earlier but can someone explain what I am doing wrong in detail?

I can not seem to debug it as I know minimal php.

```
<?php 
$rootPath = realpath('./uploads');
//make zip file
$zip = new ZipArchive();
$zip->open('file.zip', ZipArchive::CREATE | ZipArchive::OVERWRITE);
$nfiles = glob($rootPath.'*.{aiff}', GLOB_BRACE);     
$files = array_rand($nfiles, 20);
foreach($files as $file)  {
    $pathtofile = $nfiles[$file];
    if (!$file->isDir())
    {
        // Get path for current file
        $filePath = $pathtofile->getRealPath();
        $relativePath = str_replace($rootPath, "", $file);
        // Add file to zip
        $zip->addFile($filePath, $relativePath);
    }
}
//-------------------------------------------//
$zip->close();
header('Content-Type: application/zip');
header('Content-disposition: attachment;
filename='.'generatedsounds.zip');
header('Content-Length: ' . filesize('file.zip'));
readfile('file.zip');
if(file_exists('file.zip'))
{
    unlink('file.zip');
}
?>
```

Comment: what is the problem? whats not working? what errors do you get?

Comment: What is your problem? What happens when you run the code? *Does* it run?

Comment: What I did is something such as this: `<a href="/my/path/file.php" download="">Download file</a>`. Worked for me :)

Comment: it just did this http://samplepackgenerator.com/phDownloader.php

Comment: Improved code formatting, improved tags, and improved title.

Comment: The error that I'm seeing there is that you are running `Varnish` in front of your web site. Because you are trying to generate a new, random collection of files each time, you should tell varnish to 'pass' for that URL (i.e. don't attempt to cache the response).

Answer (score 0):

You're calling `->isDir()` method which is not defined, And you're calling `->getRealPath()` which is also not defined.

And you're getting all files then selecting 20 random files from the array (why??)

While you are rewriting the headers, errors won't be shown in browser, try without rewriting headers which means it's kept as html header and test until you get a binary file output then add the headers back so you have a working code.